# Laravel link to controller action

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

i want to have link to controller action from form and ajax request. bu i can not to do it. and i get this error:

```
ErrorException

Route [admin.profile.update] not defined. (View: /var/www/alachiq/app/views/back_end/layouts/profile.blade.php)
```

my form on profile.blade.php:

```
{{ Form::model($profile, array('action' => array('profileController@update', $profile->id), 'method' => 'PUT', 'id' => 'frm')) }}
```

and ajax request into that:

```
$.post("{{ route('admin.profile.update', $profile->id) }}",
```

**my Route:**

```
Route::controller('admin/profile', 'ProfileController', array('index'=>'profile.index','update'=>'profile.update') );
```

**my controller:**

```
public function getIndex()
{
    $profiles = Auth::user();
    return  View::make('back_end.layouts.profile')->with('profile', $profiles);
}

public function postUpdate($id)
{
     ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

XHTML 1.x forms only support GET and POST. GET and POST are the only allowed values for the "method" attribute.
Is there a reason you want to send a PUT request via an HTML form?

secondly change your form to

```
echo Form::open(array('action' => 'ProfileController@postUpdate','class' => '','id' => ''))
```

routes

```
Route::controller('admin/profile', 'ProfileController');
```

Comment: .i do not khnow it.thanks. then how to fix `$.post("<?php echo route('ProfileController@postUpdate', $profile->id); ?>",`

Comment: submitting ajax requests is like any other request, you should be able to parse the $profile->id as a hidden input field.

$.post("admin/profile", function( data ) {
 //do something
});

Comment: thanks. i'm change `$.post` and put `$profile->id` as hidden input tag. witch name must be parse that? `<input type="hidden" name='id' value="{{$profile->id}}" />` is `id  : $('[name=id]').val(),` currect?